# regex in perl script

Tags: regex, perl

I have a file with many lines from the following format

```
 00000000000 00000000 0 MMM_WR  0            000004            00000abc
 00000000000 00000000 0 MMM_WR  0            000008            0000000c
...
```

I want to extract the last 2 words into variables in my perl script and print them

I tried

```
$line =~ m/^.+  MMM_WR  0\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)/;

 print $1;
 print $2;
```

but $1 and $2 are always uninitialized

any advise? please

Comment: You can use regex `$line =~ /MMM_WR\s+0\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)/;` to extract data of interest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$line =~ m/^.+  MMM_WR  0\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)/;
```

This regex expects two spaces in front of `MMM_WR`

```
 00000000000 00000000 0 MMM_WR  0            000004            00000abc
```

This line provides only a single space before `MMM_WR`. Thus, your regex (which expects twp spaces) cannot match. If you fix the regex to only expect a single space it works.

Answer (score 4):

You have two spaces before `MMM_WR` where you should have one.

```
$line =~ m/^.+ MMM_WR  0\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)/;
```

This sort of thing is safer done with `split`. Split it up on whitespace and grab the fields you want.

```
my @fields = split(/\s+/, $line);
```

However, this looks like a fixed width format which is better handled with `unpack`. See [perlpacktut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlpacktut.html#Packing-Text) for more on that.

Answer (score 3):

There seems to be only one space before `MMM_WR` in your data, but the regex contains two.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string into array and print two last elements

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

while(<DATA>) {
    my @data = (split ' ')[5,6];
    say join ' ', @data;
}

__DATA__
 00000000000 00000000 0 MMM_WR  0            000004            00000abc
 00000000000 00000000 0 MMM_WR  0            000008            0000000c
```

Output

```
000004 00000abc
000008 0000000c
```

Other variation with regex match

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

while (<DATA>) {
    my @data;
    @data = $_ =~ /MMM_WR\s+\d\s+(\d{6})\s+(.+)/;
    say join ' ', @data;
}

__DATA__
 00000000000 00000000 0 MMM_WR  0            000004            00000abc
 00000000000 00000000 0 MMM_WR  0            000008            0000000c
```

Output

```
000004 00000abc
000008 0000000c
```

The data of interest can be extracted with unpack

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

while (<DATA>) {
    my @data = (unpack("A45A6A12A8",$_))[1,3];
    say join ' ', @data;
}

__DATA__
 00000000000 00000000 0 MMM_WR  0            000004            00000abc
 00000000000 00000000 0 MMM_WR  0            000008            0000000c
```

Output

```
000004 00000abc
000008 0000000c
```

Variation by utilizing 'substr'

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

while (<DATA>) {
    my @data;
    $data[0] = substr $_, 45, 6;
    $data[1] = substr $_, 63, 8;
    say join ' ', @data;
}

__DATA__
 00000000000 00000000 0 MMM_WR  0            000004            00000abc
 00000000000 00000000 0 MMM_WR  0            000008            0000000c
```

Output

```
000004 00000abc
000008 0000000c
```